# How to change ancestor of an NDB record?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the High-Replication Datastore (I'm using NDB), the consistency is eventual. In order to get a guaranteed complete set, ancestor queries can be used. Ancestor queries also provide a great way to get all the "children" of a particular ancestor with kindless queries. In short, being able to leverage the ancestor model is hugely useful in GAE.

The problem I seem to have is rather simplistic. Let's say I have a contact record and a message record. A given contact record is being treated as the ancestor for each message. However, it is possible that two contacts are created for the same person (user error, different data points, whatever). This situation produces two contact records, which have messages related to them.

I need to be able to "merge" the two records, and bring put all the messages into one big pile. Ideally, I'd be able to modify ancestor for one of the record's children.

The only way I can think of doing this, is to create a mapping and make my app check to see if record has been merged. If it has, look at the mappings to find one or more related records, and perform queries against those. This seems hugely inefficient. Is there more of "by the book" way of handling this use case?

Comment: to me it sounds like it will depends on how your datamodel looks like. how do you decide if 2 records have to be merged?

Comment: Good question - since this is in a thought stage, let's assume user input.

Comment: so if you want to merge based on a specific field of the userinput (lets say mail) you query the datastore first and see if a record with that email already exists and move on from there. if the app is new and you dont have records already then i suggest you create the record with the keyname/id based on the email to be able to query by id.

Comment: you are assuming that this can be caught on input, what if records are modified by users. If you are trying to model an address book, this is a common issue.

Comment: whenever a record has to be created/updated you need to check if it already exists. modified by users or not. who else can modify a record if not the user?

Comment: you are missing the point entirely - if you already have multiple records, what do you do with them and associated children? (assume all checks failed beforehand)

Comment: deleting my answer completely because of the misinterpretation if the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to change the ancestor of an entity is to delete the old one and create a new one with a new key. This must be done for all child (and grand child, etc) entities in the ancestor path. If this isn't possible, then your listed solution works.

This is required because the ancestor path of an entity is part of its unique key. Parents of entities (i.e., entities in the ancestor path) need not exist, so changing a parent's key will leave the children in the datastore with no parent.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for a more efficient solution, but this makes perfect sense.